# Authenticate Subdirectories

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, .htpasswd

Here's a picture of a folder inside the root directory my website:
[image: Directory]

I want to have htaccess require an authentication to access any of these folders. So no one can type in `www.domain.com/Folder/CSS` and access it without the correct username and password. So far I've tried:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^*">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Login"
    AuthUserFile /disks/*/*/Folder/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</DirectoryMatch>
```

This is to make it secure all the subdirectories (`classes, cs, images, js`) but instead when I type in `www.domain.com/Folder/Front.php` it comes up with:

```
Internal Server Error
```

With no console error. How do I make htaccess authenticate all the subdirectories (BUT NOT FRONT.PHP!)?

Answer (score 0):

Try change the DirectoryMatch regex to `/(.+)`

There is a tester for regex [here](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm#experiment)...

Hope that helps

Cheers
Robin

Ps: what do the apache logs say? Have you turned on logging.

Comment: This didn't work and I don't have access to the logs. I've tried `"/(.+)"`, `/(.+)`, `"^/(.+)"`, `^/(.+)`. None of them worked. Any ideas?

Comment: and if you put the following inside the directorymatch  <Files Frontpage.php> Satisfy any </Files>    That won't catch just  /   but if you type the page name then it will not ask for password...

Comment: so do you have any other solution?

Comment: Nope sorry mate. Can't get it working. Tried different things like: `([^/].*[/])` and `(^[/])` and `(/.*/).*` and `(^/[^/]*$)` and `^[/.*/]` etc, but none of them seem to 'get' the root without anything in the url. Can I recommend if it is the main page to do a R=301 on / to /Frontpage.php. Your problem goes away then because you can simple match all real files with a FilesMatch directive and then `Satisfy any` them... Hope that works for you...